# IOS: nsxmlparser with special characters

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsxmlparser

In my app I do an xmlparser but I have a problem during parser because in a tag I have a special letter "è" and it read it as "\U00e8"; and it close a tag of my xml...and I have an error in my parsing...

I set my path in utf-8 in this way

```
NSString *path = @"emaple.com";

NSError *error;
NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSString * dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

affayfeed = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

but I have the same problem...why?

Comment: In your `foundCharacters` method are you using `[NSMutableString appendString:]` to piece together your character stream?

Comment: Are you certain that all your encoding matches up? Generally, the escaped unicode characters are adapted automatically.

Comment: Your xml file should begin with a line similar to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Make sure that is actually UTF-8. If the file is properly encoded, it should be able to just read it in as it's written.